# Oracle Apex IR subscription not working

Tags: oracle, database-mail, reporting, oracle-apex

I have configured apex instance to use smtp email, and I can send email with IR when using download option from action menu. But the IR subscription is not sending emails. 
I have checked there is no record on APEX_MAIL_LOG and APEX_MAIL_QUEUE.
Any idea how to troubleshoot problem?